# Check if python script was triggered by jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, environment-variables, parameter-passing

i got a python script in my project. Depending on whether it was run *manually* or via *Jenkins*, I need to respond to it differently.
The only solution I came up with so far was to set an environment variable via Jenkins and check this var in the script.

Has anyone had a similar problem and could somehow solve it differently ?

Comment: You could pass an argument to it when you run it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to avoid setting an env variable, but still prefer using an existing env var you might want to use https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/#EnvInjectPlugin-BuildCauses which exposes following variables in the Env variables:
BUILD_CAUSE=MANUALTRIGGER
BUILD_CAUSE_MANUALTRIGGER=true in case of manual trigger. It internally checks which cause(s) triggered the build, which can be many like SCMTriggerCause, TimerTriggerCause etc.